# Error on Uploading Program to ESP8266 via Foca v2.2 (USB to TTL Adapter)

Tags: esp8266

### BACKGROUND

To test the capability of uploading program to ESP8266,  I use an empty program with only a blank setup function and a blank loop function. The result showed me that there are a **espcomm_sync error** and a **espcomm_open error**. Any idea to solve this problem?

---

### HARDWARE

### [image: Foca v2.2] [image: ESP8266]

---

### PIN CONNECTION

```
  Foca v2.2 <-> ESP8266
        TXD <-> RXD
        RXD <-> TXD
        DTR <-> RST

Arduino UNO <-> ESP8266
        GND <-> GND
       3.3V <-> Vcc
```

---

### PIN DIAGRAMS

Foca v2.2
[image]

ESP8266
[image]

---

### ON LINUX UBUNTU 15.04

[image]

---

### ON WINDOWS 10

[image]

### REFERENCE

---

Bring IoT to Arduino, together [Getting Started] - http://www.arduinesp.com/getting-started

Comment: The link you provide describes 3 possible scenarios. None of them corresponds to your pin connections on foca. If problem persists after correcting the DTR and RST connections try to use the manual setup first.

Comment: @Personagem - Now I removed the connection `RST <-> GPIO0` and got the same result in both windows and ubuntu but the uploading problem is still not solved.

Answer (score 1):

by the comments I think you are not understanding correctly how to connect Reset and GPIO_0 of ESP. To set esp-01 into flash mode (to program) you need to set GPIO_0 Low (GND) and then also apply Low on RST ESP pin.
To debug the things and be certain that there is no hardware problem let just start by doing these connections:

```
Foca v2.2 <-> ESP =1
      TXD <-> RXD
      RXD <-> TXD
      GND <-> GND
  Arduino <-> ESP 01
     3.3V <-> 3.3V
     3.3V <-> CH_PD
     GND  <-> GND
```

Now, with a wire, **connect GPIO_0 to ground**. With another wire, **briefly** connect **RST of the ground** to make ESP reset. You should be now in flash mode. Remove the connection on GPIO_0 and make it float. Now upload the code.

**Note:** this is basically the option C on the link you provide. If you have some buttons you can make it too:
[image: Manually Flash]
<sub>(source: [arduinesp.com](http://www.arduinesp.com/arduinesp/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/TTL-to-ESP01-blink-upload-and-reset-button.jpg))</sub>

**Now, does the code upload in Arduino IDE?**

If the answer is still no, try to add a small capacitor between 3.3v and ground.

If the answer is yes, now you can move on and try the other options described in the link you provide. I recommend using the option A:

[image: Automatic Upload]
<sub>(source: [arduinesp.com](http://www.arduinesp.com/arduinesp/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/TTL-to-ESP01-blink-NPN.png))</sub>

Any generic npn transistor should work

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I solved connecting GPIO0 to GND and connecting RST to GND a while after uploading and then leave it floating while uploading